# Strange using React stateless components

Tags: reactjs, stateless

Does anyone you know the reason to use react stateless component for huge components, with methods defined like variable, etc. I’ve recently joined to the project where used approach like this. I am confused a lot.

I guess it is better to use small components, but still

Maybe there is some logical explanation on it, like performance, etc.

simple code example:

```
const myComponent = ({p1, p2, p3}) => {
    const buttonProps = {
        className: 'button',
        onClick: () => { console.log('clicked'); }
    };
    const getButtonName = () => 'Submit'; 
    const getButton = () => {
        return (
            <button ...buttonProps>{getButtonName()}<button>
        );
    }
    /* a lot of defined objects like above */
    return (
        <div>
            {getButton()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Main question is** why there used methods like getButton() instead of creating MyButton component. I guess it would be easy to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: A `stateless component` means that it has no `state` and the pattern you show above could had been implemented just as well in a `class` component that has `state` defined, for example in the `render()` method - this isn't a something that's specific to `stateless components`. As for the pattern itself, if what you're showing is exactly like that, honestly I have no idea why this approach and it most likely doesn't make sense to do any of this.

Comment: However, if there's a reusable function that makes sense, for example to assign `props` for a button based on condition, or whatever, such as `getButton('red')` which returns `<button style={{ color: 'red' }} />` then that'd be the only case where it'd make sense to use such approach and it wouldn't feel weird. Otherwise, what you have shown above, doesn't really make sense and should be avoided.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not talking about avoiding `stateless components`, I am talking about avoiding creating pointless objects and functions inside a `stateless component` that create unnecessary abstractions - doing `return (<div><button className="button" onClick={() => {}}>Submit</button></div>)` would had been a lot smarter approach and a lot easier for me to understand what's going on instead of figuring out what each function call does.

Comment: I guess, I've asked in wrong way. I understand why there is stateless component. The question is, why methods like getButton() used instead of creating separate Button component?

Comment: I don't know the context to give you a better explanation why things were done this way, perhaps it's better to ask the developer that wrote the code for the reasoning behind this approach. You're right though - if you need a reusable component, then it absolutely makes more sense to create a separate `Button` component rather than creating those unnecessary abstractions as seen above.

Comment: Agree. Creating reusable components is a much better approach and although I am not sure the benefits the approach adopted would bring, I would highly recommend creating reusable components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `stateless component` means that is has no `state` and the `React` component in your example would be considered a `functional component`. As for the pattern itself, it's something that could be implemented in a `class component` as well - it's not something specific to only `functional components`.

For example, the above code could had been written like the one below, and it would yield the same exact result:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const buttonProps = {
      className: `button`,
      onClick: () => {}
    }
    const getButtonName = () => `Submit`
    const getButton = () => {
      return (
        <button {...buttonProps}>{getButtonName()}</button>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>{getButton()}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

I don't know the context so it's hard to figure out why things are done this way - it'd be better to ask the developer responsible for choosing to write components this way to figure out the reason.

Unfortunately, or fortunately, `React` is not-opinionated, and people are free to do however they please, which may result in "strange" patterns that are **not** always good.

The code snippet you provided creates unnecessary abstractions that are not clear at first glance - I had to figure out what `getButton` does, then go to `getButtonName` to see what was being rendered inside the `button` element, and then I had to search for `buttonProps` to figure out what `props` were being passed.

If you really need a reusable function that returns a component, then why not just do it the "`React`" way?

```js
function Button({ children, ...rest }) {
  const defaultProps = {
    className: `button`,
    onClick: () => {}
  }
  const props = { ...defaultProps, ...rest }

  return (
    <button {...props}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Which then, going back to your example, can be used as in the following example:

```js
// by the way, start with an uppercase when naming React components
const MyComponent = ({ p1, p2, p3 }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button>I am a button #1!</Button>
      <Button
        onClick={() => console.log(`HelloWorld`)}
      >
        I am a button #2 with a custom `onClick` handler!
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This approach is a lot better and cleaner, so just as you suggested in the comments, `getButton` should written as an actual `React` component.

Answer (score 1):

A stateful component that extends React.Component has a lot of extras.  You are basically importing all the variables and functions built in to React.Component such as lifecycle functions.  If you don't need them, then stateless just creates a lighter component.  For example, when your component mounts, a stateful component will call componentDidMount() but a stateless doesn't even have componentDidMount().

Edit: to answer your more specific question:
That function kind of is a component, a functional component, made to be reusable but inside a functional component's render function this component can't be called with the <> syntax. It's inside another component so that it's scope is limited to the parent and so that it has access to props. It's kind of opinion-based because using one kind of component over the other is just a balance of readability, reusability, and functionality.

Comment: thank you, I guess I've asked a wrong way. Why do not create separate component fro the button and use it in myComponent?

Answer (score 1):

In React you can either have class-based components, or function-based components (functional components).

Functional components are generally easier to test and understand, and they are lighter.

The trend in the React world is towards function-based components. This has been the case even more so in the last year or so, with the introduction of hooks (i.e. `useState`, `useEffect`, etc.) which allow you to have a light functional component, but with access to the things that gave class-based components their extra abilities.

There's nothing wrong per se with class-based components, but the trend is away from them, so I'm not surprised to hear you say you joined a project that does not use them.

You may be interested in one of the React Conf videos from 2018 that went into the introduction of hooks: [React Conf 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpw9EHDh2bM) The relevant part starts at about 11:30.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I've asked in wrong way. Why do not create separate component for button instead of using getButton() method?